# Accessing Data in csv.reader

Tags: python

I'm trying to access a csv file of currency pairs using csv.reader.  The first column shows dates, the first row shows the currency pair eg.USD/CAD.  I can read in the file but cannot access the currency pairs data to perform simple calculations.

I've tried using next(x) to skip header row (currency pairs).  If i do this, i get a Typeerror: csv reader is not subscriptable.

```
path = x
file = open(path)
dataset = csv.reader(file, delimiter = '\t',)
header = next(dataset)
header
```

Output shows the header row which is

```
['Date,USD,Index,CNY,JPY,EUR,KRW,GBP,SGD,INR,THB,NZD,TWD,MYR,IDR,VND,AED,PGK,HKD,CAD,CHF,SEK,SDR']
```

I expect to be able to access the underlying currency pairs but i'm getting the type error as noted above.  Is there a simple way to access the currency pairs, for example I want to use USD.describe() to get simple statistics on the USD currency pair.

How can i move from this stage to accessing the data underlying the header row?

Comment: Can you clarify when you get the `Type error`? From what I read, `header` is being correctly assigned. Please include also code where you try to read the next rows in the file.

Comment: Please include the part of the code that produces the Exception. And always include the complete Traceback - format it as code.

Comment: Also a sample of the data (few rows are enough) could be useful

Comment: Did you attempt to follow [any examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) from the docs?

Comment: `describe()` is pandas. Are you using pandas? If so, you do not need to use the `csv` module, use `pandas.read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

try this example

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.Reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(f'\t{row[0]} {row[1]} {row[3]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's apparent from the output of your header row that the columns are comma-delimited rather than tab-delimited, so instead of passing `delimiter = '\t'` to `csv.reader`, you should let it use the default delimiter `','` instead:

```
dataset = csv.reader(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your delimiter is `'\t'`? In first row your delimiter is `','`... Anyway you can skip first row by doing `file.readline()` before using it by `csv.reader`:

```py
import csv

example = """Date,USD,Index,CNY,JPY,EUR,KRW,GBP,SGD,INR,THB,NZD,TWD,MYR,IDR,VND,AED,PGK,HKD,CAD,CHF,SEK,SDR
1-2-3\tabc\t1.1\t1.2
4-5-6\txyz\t2.1\t2.2
"""

with open('demo.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(example)

with open('demo.csv') as f:
    f.readline()
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
# ['1-2-3', 'abc', '1.1', '1.2']                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# ['4-5-6', 'xyz', '2.1', '2.2']
```

I think that you need something else... Can you add to your question:

- example of first 3 lines in your csv
- Example of what you'd like to access:

  - is using `row[0]`, `row[1]` enough for you?
  - or do you want "named" access like `row['Date'], row['USD']`,
  - or you want something more complex like `data_by_date['2019-05-01']['USD']`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to elaborate some statistics `pandas` is your friend. No need to use the `csv` module, use `pandas.read_csv`.

```
import pandas

filename = 'path/of/file.csv'
dataset = pandas.read_csv(filename, sep = '\t') #or whatever the separator is
```

`pandas.read_csv` uses the first line as the header automatically.
To see statistics, simply do:

```
dataset.describe()
```

Or for a single column:

```
dataset['column_name'].describe()
```